# How to reverse all words in a string? C++

Tags: c++, c, string, reverse, words

So.. I'm sorry I doubleposted. I really didn't know how this site works. However, I'm changing my whole question here so that it's more understandable. And here it is:

```
char s[1002];
cin.getline(s, 1002, '\n');
int k;
int p = strlen(s);
strcat(s, " ");

for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++)
{
    if (s[i] == ' ')
    {

        for (k = i - 1; (k != -1) && (s[k] != ' '); k--)
            cout << s[k];
        cout << " ";

    }
}
```

' ' , ',' , '.' and ';' should be delimiters but I've managed to pull it to work only with ' ' (intervals).

I cannot use `std::string` as I'm doing this for a homework where I need to make a very specific function - `char const* reverseWordsOnly(const char*)`.

What should the code do?

```
Input: Reversing the  letters, is; really hard.

Output: gnisreveR eht  srettel, si; yllaer drah.
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an `std::string` for this?

Comment: Cause in school they teach us only what I've written. I found out about std::string just today and am not confident enough to use it.

Comment: Also, `i = 0` and `k = i - 1`? And what's the `strcat` for? You'll have to scan the whole string for " words", i.e. for sequences of letters. If you have identified the words, revert them.

Comment: I agree but as I said I ain't too familiar with std::string and I can't possibly use such things as std::reverse as it is for homework and I gotta do it the hard way.

Comment: @ZacHowland: That answer is about the "round way other the" double reverse. I think the OP wants to have the words "eht rehto yaw dnuor" withpunctuation and spaces still in place.

Comment: @user3213110 You can, and should, take a look at the source code for algorithms like `std::reverse` as they are not complicated and will help you later.

Comment: @MOehm There are about 2 dozen questions asking the same type of question.  Either way, it has already been asked and answered many times.

Comment: @user3213110 Are you allowed to use `strtok`? (this is the standard C function for examining individual words in a string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I still feel this is a duplicate, the thought process for solving this would be this:

1. Write a function that returns true for alphabet characters (a-z and A-Z), and false otherwise.
2. Start at the beginning of the string
3. Find the next alphabet character, note its location (start)
4. Find the next non-alphabet character, note its location (end)
5. Reverse the characters in the range [start, end)
6. Repeat steps 3-5 until the end of the string

All of this becomes very easy when you use `std::string` and algorithms like `std::reverse` instead of using raw arrays and custom.  Since you are allowed to use `std::cin` and `std::cout` (`<iostream>`), the argument against using `<string>` is a silly one.

Comment: This question was asked at least 3 times, but the answers there don't help: OP could just replace his code by the one found in the answer, and we certainly don't want this.

Comment: @anatolyg I'm not sure I follow you.  What is it you are trying to convey?

Comment: I related to your first sentence ("this is a duplicate") - even though this question was asked before, it needs a new answer; you cannot just redirect to an older similar question.

Comment: If the question is a duplicate (which I feel it is), that is exactly what is to be done.  That is exactly why there is a "closed as duplicate" option.

Comment: I editted my question. Hope it's more understandable now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @user3213110 With the edit, the process you must implement is described in this answer.  As this is an assignment, I cannot give you code as that would result in me doing the assignment for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the string in another array without the symbols first and then reverse the new array. For example if you want to ignore a comma (,) or semicolon (;) you can write something like

```
while(i <= p)
{
    if (s[i] == ',' || s[i] == ';')
    {
        i++;

    }
    else
    {
       temp[j]=s[i];
       j++;
       i++;
    }
 }
```

Then you can reverse the temp array.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted. Problem is I don't need to ignore them in the new string. I need them to act as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just printing the letters like this

```
for (k = i - 1; (k != -1) && (s[k] != ' '); k--)
    cout << s[k];
cout << " ";
```

Check to see if you need to ignore the letter, like this

```
for (k = i - 1; (k != -1) && (s[k] != ' '); k--)
    if((s[k] != ',') && (s[k] != ';') && ...other ignored chars...)
       cout << s[k];
cout << " ";
```

Comment: Nothing really changes...

Comment: @user3213110, i saw your edit, and see that i misunderstood your need. Tell me if you still have trouble coming up with the solution

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, I do. Still haven't figured out how to pull it out. I tried to use an if clause for every single delimiter the way I used it for the interval but it only gets worse.

Comment: Did you try implementing Zac Howlands algorithm? it seems correct. if you did and still no success, post your code and we'll see whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char s[1001],ch;
    int c=0;    // for counting how many words are in the array
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){    // input string until new line
        if ((ch>='a' && ch<='z') || (ch>='A' && ch<='Z'))   // check if the input character is a letter or symbol
            s[c++] = ch;    // if its a letter then insert into the array
    }

    for (int i=c-1;i>=0;i--)    // print the array in reverse order
        cout<<s[i]<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need the letters of the words reversed, not the word order.